# PostgreSQL - Hierarchical List of All tables

Tags: php, postgresql

I need to list all table of my database (PostgreSQL) in hierarchical order.
Thats mean: If the table "user" have a Foreign Key to table "role", then it must to come after the table "role" in the list.

Something equivalent at to:

```
EXEC sp_msdependencies @intrans = 1
```

In SQL Server.

I tried that, but without success:

```
SELECT
    pt.table_name as tablename,
    string_agg(DISTINCT ccu.table_name, ',') AS reftable
FROM information_schema.tables pt
LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns c
    ON c.table_name = pt.table_name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tc
    ON tc.table_name = pt.table_name AND tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
    ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name AND kcu.column_name = c.column_name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
    ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE pt.table_schema = 'public'
GROUP BY pt.table_name,pt.table_type
ORDER BY pt.table_type DESC, COUNT(TRUE) ASC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a simple `SELECT`. You might need a recursive query.

`information_schema` appears to be particularly poorly suited to this case, as it assumes that constraint names are unique within a schema, something which Postgres doesn't enforce. In other words, if you have two constraints with the same name, I don't see any way to tell them apart in `constraint_column_usage`. So you may be better off using Postgres' own catalogs.

This appears to work, though I haven't thoroughly tested it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ref (tbl, reftbl, depth) AS (
  SELECT pg_class.oid, NULL::oid, 0
  FROM pg_class
  JOIN pg_namespace ON
    pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
  WHERE 
    relkind = 'r' AND
    nspname = 'public' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM pg_constraint
      WHERE 
        conrelid = pg_class.oid AND
        contype = 'f'
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT conrelid, ref.tbl, ref.depth + 1
  FROM ref
  JOIN pg_constraint ON
    confrelid = ref.tbl AND
    contype = 'f'
)
SELECT
  tbl::regclass::text as tablename,
  string_agg(DISTINCT reftbl::regclass::text, ',') as reftables
FROM ref
GROUP BY tablename
ORDER BY max(depth)
```

Comment: Hm, thanks for your answer. But your example dont return nothing, just always "Query is running" without a end. :D

Comment: @Marcelo: Do you have cyclic references? There's no way to order them if this is the case.